# QRScanner use front facing camera

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to get the QRScanner by LittleMonkey used by CodenameOne to use the "selfie" camera. However I get ERROR 100 Format Camera unavailable. It there a setting in the Display class to change the camera selection?

Comment: This is something you should probably refer to the author by posting an issue here https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/QRScanner/issues